# .htaccess file and folder with the same name

Tags: .htaccess

I am new at .htaccess and I have a PHP file called products.php and a folder with the same name called /products.

I want to create a friendly URL for the products page of my website a I would like to know if it is possible to execute the products.php file outside the folder /products.

I am using the .htaccess code below.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^products/([a-z0-9-]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ products.php?id=$2&nome=$1 [NC]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you try it and it didn't work ? if it didn't, try removing this line :

```
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
```